# I can log into my user account, but when I use the same password in terminal, it fails

Tags: command-line, password

So I'm relatively new to Ubuntu, so bear with me. I recently went to work and play around in the terminal. When the terminal asks for my password, I type in the same password I use to log into my user account. When i hit enter, it tells me that it's incorrect. This can't be, as I use the same password to log in.

Comment: Can you share a sample command you are using?

Comment: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys BBEBDCB318AD50EC6865090613B00F1FD2C19886

Comment: Are you the administrator on the machine?

Comment: are you sure you are using the same user name too?

Comment: I'm pretty sure. I'm the only user on this computer. I just installed Ubuntu last night, so only my account is on here, other than guest that is.

Comment: Try using the same command, but use `gksudo` instead of `sudo`. You should see a prompt for password. Let me know if that works

Comment: When i try gksudo, it tells me that it's not installed. Then asks for sudo passwd.

Comment: perhaps reset password in recovery mode?

Comment: Try `pkexec passwd <username>`. This should definitely work. Enter you current password twice and your `sudo` should be back to normal.

Comment: I tried, but I get - bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'newline'

Comment: terminal shows my name as "mdstandeford@mdstandeford", and I know that my username is mdstandeford.

Comment: I believe you didn't change the username part from the command. You have change the last part to your username without the `<>`

Comment: ohhhhhh......yeah, it worked now. Thank you so much! I really do like the help this community gives to new users!

Comment: I have posted this as an answer. Mark it as an answer so that others can refer to it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pkexec passwd <username>`. Replace the last part with your username without the `<>`. Enter the password twice and this should fix your issue.